# Can I assign Magic Trackpad 3-finger swipe up/down to scroll to top/bottom?

Tags: macos, magic-trackpad

I have the trackpad on my Macbook pro set up to scroll to top/bottom on a 3-finger vertical swipe. As far as I can tell, that option isn't there for a Magic Trackpad.

It's very confusing to have both devices behave differently on the same gestures. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Magic Trackpad did this right out of the box. I believe you should select "Swipe to navigate."

[image]

Comment: Yes, the setting is there but it doesn't seem to work in all applications. It works in Firefox (on most pages), but not in Chrome, for example.

Comment: @Lizzan: That might be an application specific issue. I'm guessing it maps to the "Home" and "End" keys, perhaps Chrome doesn't recognize those?

Comment: I would have thought so too, but it seems it's not that simple. "Home" and "End" work in Chrome, three-finger swipe doesn't.

Comment: @Lizzan: it's because Chrome does not support the up and down 3 finger swipe.  It support left and right (back and forward).  You can't do it on a macbook touchpad either.

Comment: Turns out it does work, but I was using Chrome most of the time to test it.